# Fisheye + Freestyle

Tags: freestyle, fisheye

I would like to render a freestyle line over a render with fisheye lens in 2.9. Is this possible?[image]

Comment: I found [this](https://vimeo.com/9743923). It happened 10 years ago and he even said it was simple. Someone with knowledge of the code will be able to reproduce it in 2.9.

Comment: That's excellent, except the link in the description is broken. It's a good lead, though!

Comment: Please share your progress here. I'm also a demander for 'Line Render in Fisheeye Camera'. Another piece of information is that you can achieve line in fisheeye in Softimage XSI. I forgot my knowledge now, but I did it 9 years ago at university.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to introduce you to a way to get lines in fisheye camera from the blender in a way other than freestyle.

There is also a way to output normal and z-depth passes from Cycles using a panoramic camera and connect them to [Edgenode](http://blendernpr.org/edge-node-v1-2-4-july-2015/), a node tree for compositor provided by BNPR, to obtain lines. Instead, because this line is aliased and is clean and has no displacing effect, you can take it to After Effects, convert it to anti-aliasing with [OLM Smooter](https://olm.co.jp/rd/technology/tools/), and apply displacement effects to achieve analog effects.

**NOTE** : The z-depth output from the panoramic camera can cause wavy artifacts.
Use the *Detected Edges [Normal]* output instead of the *Edges Out* output.
[image]

Yes, it can feel quite complicated. How nice would it be if Freestyle supported the Blender's panoramic camera!
(In addition, I hope Freestyle get self intersection function.)